# What is the Wayland equivalent of xinput list?

Tags: x11, wayland, libinput

I am running a [userspace driver for a /dev/uinput device](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet) in a Wayland desktop session. The instructions suggest running `xinput list` to confirm that the device is detected.

Of course, xinput is an X.org application. What is the equivalent command for Wayland? (A GNOME GUI equivalent is acceptable.)

Comment: related: https://forums.bitfire.at/topic/1696

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On Debian the command is:

```
$ sudo libinput list-devices
# requires the libinput-tools package
```

On [arch-linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Configuration):

```
# libinput list-devices
```

To list just the device names, no details, use grep:

```
$ sudo libinput list-devices | grep Device
```

Comment: That does a part of xinput's functionality. How woule one create and remove logical master devices (I think they're called "seats" in Wayland lingo...)?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `sudo evemu-describe` to list the input devices found in `/dev/input/event*`. It is interactive unless you give it a specific device from the list.

Answer (score 2):

According to `man 5 sway-input`, you could use `swaymsg -t get_inputs`.

Comment: Nice one! This is what you need to do if you need to have device specific configuration (e.g. enabling natural scroll for the touchpad in the sway config) because this command gives you the the identifier you need for that.