# Ubuntu -- Wireless mouse now showing in 'xinput list' but it's present in 'lsusb' and working correctly

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, xinput

I want to enable scrolling with my mouse click and I was following this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down) but I failed at start because when I'm running `xinput list` in terminal it's not showing my mouse there. However it is present when I'm run `lsusb`. I'm using Xiaomi Wireless mouse. Any ideas how can I make my mouse to appear in `xinput list` or skip this step although keep following the 'tutorial' which I have linked?

EDIT:
Terminal respond from @Kamil Maciorowski instructions `{ cat; xinput list; } | diff - <(xinput list)`:

```
$ { cat; xinput list; } | diff - <(xinput list)
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
3d2
< ⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17                id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
4a4
> ⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17                id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Please connect the mouse (receiver) so it works; then run in Bash `{ cat; xinput list; } | diff - <(xinput list)`. The command will "stall", this is by design. Disconnect the mouse (receiver) fully. Hit Ctrl+d. The command should exit. Is the output empty? If not empty, what is it? Do not respond in comments; [edit] the question and add information there.

Comment: I know nothing about Wayland. Maybe this will advance your research: [What is the Wayland equivalent of `xinput list`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/426944/108618)